Regexp in findstr to find URLs in txt files in all subfolders
I struggle with a pretty simple CMD task.
I have a root folder (C:\folder) in which I have many subfolders and each of them contains different kind of files. I want to search all txt files in all subfolders to find URL links. At the end I want to put of all links into a single file.
My regexp to find URL is like:
(https?|ftp|file):\/\/\)?[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]+[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]
and it works
My last idea was:
for /R C:\folder %%F in (*.txt) do (
   findstr /r "(https?|ftp|file):\/\/\)?[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]+[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]"  >> results.txt
)

Can you help me? What am I missing?

I thought you needed to use /R for a regular expression (don't have access to a windows machine at the moment to check)

switching from /r to /R changed nothing

It seems likely that the regex processing of findstr.exe is not fully capable of all of the features used. Also, findstr.exe needs to be told what file it should read.

I am not sure that this regex is a universal URL identifier, but if you want to put it into a PowerShell command:
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Filter '*.txt' |
   Select-String -Pattern '(https?|ftp|file):\/\/\)?[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]+[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]'

As suggested by @mklement0:
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Filter '*.txt' |
    Select-String -Pattern '(https?|ftp|file):\/\/\)?[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]+[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]' |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value }

and:
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Filter '*.txt' |
    Select-String -Pattern '(https?|ftp|file):\/\/\)?[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]+[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]' |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value } >results.txt

I would not put the results.txt file in the same directory, since it will be included if the command is run again. Perhaps placing it in the home directory.
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Filter '*.txt' |
    Select-String -Pattern '(https?|ftp|file):\/\/\)?[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]+[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]' |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value } |
    Out-File -Path '~/results.txt'

